# Provided shape has duplicate consecutive coordinates at: (-87.2576, 90.0, NaN)

Tags: geoserver, sld, geoserver-rest-api, elasticsearch, kibana

I get the following error when I send POST request to GeoServer. This error occurs only with particular layer. Other layers work fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
  <ServiceException code="internalError">
   Rendering process failed java.io.IOException: Error executing query search Error executing query search POST
 http://localhost:9200/mytest/global_agg_traffic_data/_search: HTTP/1.1
 400 Bad Request
 {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed
 to create query: {\n \"bool\" : {\n \"must\" : [\n {\n \"bool\" : {\n
 \"must\" : [\n {\n \"match_all\" : {\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n }\n ],\n
 \"filter\" : [\n {\n \"geo_shape\" : {\n \"TriangleLocation\" : {\n
 \"shape\" : {\n \"type\" : \"polygon\",\n \"orientation\" :
 \"right\",\n \"coordinates\" : [\n [\n [\n -87.2576,\n 90.0\n ],\n [\n
 -87.2576,\n 90.0\n ],\n [\n -136.7322,\n 90.0\n ],\n [\n -136.7322,\n 90.0\n ],\n [\n -87.2576,\n 90.0\n ]\n ]\n ]\n },\n \"relation\" : \"intersects\"\n },\n \"ignore_unmapped\" : false,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n
 }\n }\n ],\n \"disable_coord\" : false,\n \"adjust_pure_negative\" :
 true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n },\n {\n \"bool\" : {\n \"should\" : [\n
 {\n \"range\" : {\n \"Traffic_intensity_data\" : {\n \"from\" :
 null,\n \"to\" : 0.0,\n \"include_lower\" : true,\n \"include_upper\"
 : true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n }\n },\n {\n \"bool\" : {\n \"must\" :
 [\n {\n \"range\" : {\n \"Traffic_intensity_data\" : {\n \"from\" :
 0.0,\n \"to\" : null,\n \"include_lower\" : false,\n \"include_upper\" : true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n }\n },\n {\n \"range\" : {\n
 \"Traffic_intensity_data\" : {\n \"from\" : null,\n \"to\" : 10.0,\n
 \"include_lower\" : true,\n \"include_upper\" : true,\n \"boost\" :
 1.0\n }\n }\n }\n ],\n \"disable_coord\" : false,\n \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n },\n {\n
 \"range\" : {\n \"Traffic_intensity_data\" : {\n \"from\" : 10.0,\n
 \"to\" : null,\n \"include_lower\" : false,\n \"include_upper\" :
 true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n }\n }\n ],\n \"disable_coord\" :
 false,\n \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n }\n
 ],\n \"disable_coord\" : false,\n \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n
 \"boost\" : 1.0\n
 }\n}","index_uuid":"ApQjY5iMR6KghzZRPUUm-w","index":"mytest"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
 shards
 failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"mytest","node":"LOQmMI11SJyen1gQOlXnug","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed
 to create query: {\n \"bool\" : {\n \"must\" : [\n {\n \"bool\" : {\n
 \"must\" : [\n {\n \"match_all\" : {\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n }\n ],\n
 \"filter\" : [\n {\n \"geo_shape\" : {\n \"TriangleLocation\" : {\n
 \"shape\" : {\n \"type\" : \"polygon\",\n \"orientation\" :
 \"right\",\n \"coordinates\" : [\n [\n [\n -87.2576,\n 90.0\n ],\n [\n
 -87.2576,\n 90.0\n ],\n [\n -136.7322,\n 90.0\n ],\n [\n -136.7322,\n 90.0\n ],\n [\n -87.2576,\n 90.0\n ]\n ]\n ]\n },\n \"relation\" : \"intersects\"\n },\n \"ignore_unmapped\" : false,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n
 }\n }\n ],\n \"disable_coord\" : false,\n \"adjust_pure_negative\" :
 true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n },\n {\n \"bool\" : {\n \"should\" : [\n
 {\n \"range\" : {\n \"Traffic_intensity_data\" : {\n \"from\" :
 null,\n \"to\" : 0.0,\n \"include_lower\" : true,\n \"include_upper\"
 : true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n }\n },\n {\n \"bool\" : {\n \"must\" :
 [\n {\n \"range\" : {\n \"Traffic_intensity_data\" : {\n \"from\" :
 0.0,\n \"to\" : null,\n \"include_lower\" : false,\n \"include_upper\" : true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n }\n },\n {\n \"range\" : {\n
 \"Traffic_intensity_data\" : {\n \"from\" : null,\n \"to\" : 10.0,\n
 \"include_lower\" : true,\n \"include_upper\" : true,\n \"boost\" :
 1.0\n }\n }\n }\n ],\n \"disable_coord\" : false,\n \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n },\n {\n
 \"range\" : {\n \"Traffic_intensity_data\" : {\n \"from\" : 10.0,\n
 \"to\" : null,\n \"include_lower\" : false,\n \"include_upper\" :
 true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n }\n }\n ],\n \"disable_coord\" :
false,\n \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n }\n }\n
 ],\n \"disable_coord\" : false,\n \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n
 \"boost\" : 1.0\n
 }\n}","index_uuid":"ApQjY5iMR6KghzZRPUUm-w","index":"mytest","caused_by":{"type":"invalid_shape_exception","reason":"Provided
 shape has duplicate consecutive coordinates at: (-87.2576, 90.0,
 NaN)"}}}]},"status":400}
   </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I have these polygons:

```
"coordinates" : [[[3.07896832,41.82473098],[3.07812279,41.82468778],[3.07884566,41.82513165],[3.07896832,41.82473098]]]

"coordinates" : [[[3.07750042,41.82564631],[3.07834561,41.8256958],[3.07762606,41.82524656],[3.07750042,41.82564631]]]
```

I can see them in GeoServer when clicking on `Layers-> visualize with OpenLayers`. But when I make a GetMap request from client-side (Kibana), I get this error.

Comment: There seem to be double vertices, as well as a line segment between -87.2576E 90.0N and  -136.7322E 90.0 N that has zero length, and might also be taken as invalid. Try to edit the shapefile and remove the points at the poles.

Comment: @AndreJ: Could you please check my update? I still do not understand why it fails. If I put the shown coordinates to another layer, there is no error message and polygons (triangles) are visualized correctly. I use Elasticgeo plugin for Geoserver 2.11 (https://github.com/ngageoint/elasticgeo).

Comment: The error message has different coordinates, I'm not sure where they come from.

Comment: @AndreJ: Yes, that's the case. I just restarted everything and now it works fine.